# Why is my server not recognizing as sent file in python when I send one back?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to send a file to a server in python and then send one back (code below). However, until I close the socket, the server doesn't recognize that the entire file has been sent. It will hang open until I close the client, in which case it will complete and recognize that the connection has been closed. If I comment out the lines sending the file back, the program completes without error.

How do I fix this so that I can send a file back?

```
import argparse
import socket
import os
import tqdm

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Use -c for client or -s for server")
parser.add_argument('-c','--client', action="store_true", help="client mode")
parser.add_argument('-s','--server', action="store_true", help="server mode")
args = parser.parse_args()
config = vars(args)
SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096 # send 4096 bytes each time step
SERVER_PORT = 19999

class commonality:
    def receivefile(self,client_socket):

        # receive the file infos
        # receive using client socket, not server socket
        received = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
        filename, filesize = received.split(SEPARATOR)
        # remove absolute path if there is
        filename = os.path.basename(filename)
        # convert to integer
        filesize = int(filesize)
        # start receiving the file from the socket
        # and writing to the file stream
        progress = tqdm.tqdm(range(filesize), f"Receiving {filename}", unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            while True:
                # read 1024 bytes from the socket (receive)
                bytes_read = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                if not bytes_read:    
                    # nothing is received
                    # file transmitting is done
                    break
                # write to the file the bytes we just received
                f.write(bytes_read)
                # update the progress bar
                progress.update(len(bytes_read))
        
        return filename
    
    def sendfile(self,s,filename):
        # get the file size
        filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
        # send the filename and filesize
        s.send(f"{filename}{SEPARATOR}{filesize}".encode())
        # start sending the file
        progress = tqdm.tqdm(range(filesize), f"Sending {filename}", unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)
        with open(filename, "rb") as f:
            while True:
                # read the bytes from the file
                bytes_read = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
                if not bytes_read:
                    # file transmitting is done
                    break
                # we use sendall to assure transimission in 
                # busy networks
                s.sendall(bytes_read)
                # update the progress bar
                progress.update(len(bytes_read))
        
        
class client(commonality):
    def clientmode(self):
        # the ip address or hostname of the server, the receiver
        host = "127.0.0.1"
        
        # the name of file we want to send, make sure it exists
        filename = "data.csv"
        # create the client socket
        s = socket.socket()
        print(f"[+] Connecting to {host}:{SERVER_PORT}")
        s.connect((host, SERVER_PORT))
        print("[+] Connected.") 
       
        self.sendfile(s,filename)
        self.receivefile(s)
        s.close()

class server(commonality):
    def servermode(self):
        SERVER_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
        # create the server socket
        # TCP socket
        s = socket.socket()
        # bind the socket to our local address
        s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
        # enabling our server to accept connections
        # 5 here is the number of unaccepted connections that
        # the system will allow before refusing new connections
        
        
        while True:
            s.listen(5)
            # print(f"[*] Listening as {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}")
            # accept connection if there is any
            client_socket, address = s.accept() 
            # if below code is executed, that means the sender is connected
            print(f"[+] {address} is connected.")
            filename = self.receivefile(client_socket)
            #render and return file in thread
            # close the client socket

            self.sendfile(client_socket,filename)
            client_socket.close()
        # close the server socket
        s.close()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if config['client']:
        client().clientmode()
    elif config['server']:
        server().servermode()
    else:
        print("You didn't read the manual, did you? Use -c to run in client mode, and -s to run as a server")
```

Comment: The only way for `receivefile()` to finish is for the socket to be closed.  The client side doesn't do that after sending its file (it immediately tries to receive a file, instead), so the server side hangs forever.  If you intend for more than one transfer to take place over a single socket, you need some other way of indicating the end of each transfer - the typical solution is to precede the file data with the length of the data to be sent, so the receiving end can tell when all of it has been received.